# java.lang.RuntimeException: Database active version is not valid for application version

Tags: oracle, command-line, x86-64, redhat, weblogic11g

I have this error when trying to deploy the Oracle Enterprise Data Quality (OEDQ) inside the weblogic server.

```
Component:
```

1)OEDQRCU = `FWM RCU 11.1.1.7.3`

2)OEDQ =  `EDQ 11.1.1.7.4`

3)Oracle Weblogic = Weblogic `10.3.6`

4)Oracle database = Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release `11.2.0.4.0` 
64bit Production

```
Chronology:
```

1)RCU Configured

2)EDQ Admin Server Configured and successfully run

3)EDQ app failed to deploy with below error:

[image]

```
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:462)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:405)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:931)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:481)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:205)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:548)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:217)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:947)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1283)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1441)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3769)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3823)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1671)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:135)
        at com.datanomic.director.databaseconfiguration.DatabaseConfigurationSupport.checkSchemaVersion(DatabaseConfigurationSupport.java:75)
        at com.datanomic.director.startup.WebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(WebApplicationContext.java:676)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
        at com.datanomic.director.startup.WebApplicationContext.refresh(WebApplicationContext.java:116)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>
<Oct 29, 2015 2:34:43 PM MYT> <Error> <oracle.edq.main> <EDQ-10308> <Database active version is not valid for application version>
<Oct 29, 2015 2:34:43 PM MYT> <Error> <org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader> <BEA-000000> <Context initialization failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: Database active version is not valid for application version
        at com.datanomic.director.startup.WebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(WebApplicationContext.java:679)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
        at com.datanomic.director.startup.WebApplicationContext.refresh(WebApplicationContext.java:116)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1868)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:149)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>
<Oct 29, 2015 2:34:43 PM MYT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Database active version is not valid for application version.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Database active version is not valid for application version
        at com.datanomic.director.startup.WebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(WebApplicationContext.java:679)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
        at com.datanomic.director.startup.WebApplicationContext.refresh(WebApplicationContext.java:116)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 29, 2015 2:34:43 PM MYT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1446100477156' for task '0'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: '
weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.RuntimeException: Database active version is not valid for application version
        at com.datanomic.director.startup.WebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(WebApplicationContext.java:679)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
        at com.datanomic.director.startup.WebApplicationContext.refresh(WebApplicationContext.java:116)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

<Oct 29, 2015 2:34:43 PM MYT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 7 task for the application 'edq'.>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but remains unanswered. 
For information, this is also an error that occurs when OEDQ is unable to connect to the repository database (as opposed to being directly related to versions of software). 
Chances are an old version of director.properties existed that was pointing the app in the wrong direction. Deleting the director.properties file and restarting Weblogic should redeploy and result in a successful start.
If this was not the issue next steps are to check that the tables were all created by RCU and that the JNDI connections look correct in WebLogic and their details are correct in the director.properties file where EDQ is deployed.